# Jet Chan's mentor stuck in Evil Genius

Tags: evil-genius

I have captured both Jet Chan and his mentor in my base. However, his mentor got out of his prison cell and now I can't capture him again. My minions ignore any tag I stick him with (capture, kill, weaken), but the cameras do pick it up. He just runs around my base in a panic. My henchmen's abilities can't target him either. Right now I'm trying to get him to run out of my base in the hope that he'll escape and I can recapture him, but he doesn't seem to want to do that. Any solutions?

Comment: Try setting the base to red alert and see if minions target him then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion was going to be let him run away and escape and you can recapture him but sadly you tried it and it didn't work. Good job in thinking of it though.

In my experience, if I had problems with an enemy I couldn't subdue I checked my minion types and their locations. 
I usually kept a high amount of social type minions around to "mind weaken" enemies instead of kill/subdue. Your problem is that although you tagged the mentor for "mind weaken", and your cameras might actually be seeing them, you might not have any social minions (diplomats, playboys, spin doctors, valets) around to take care of him. They might be busy doing something else, might be too tired to do anything or might not hear the alarms.

Try increasing the number of social minions you have, check your alarm level and try putting in more loudspeakers.